# Relative layout onpress

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

What I want is, When the `RelativeLayout` press state is active, I want the layout alpha to be `50%` and when its not I need `100%` alpha.

The following code doesn't seem to be working.

```
if (relativelayout.hasFocus()){
    relativelayout.setAlpha(0.5f);
}
```

I tried setting the background of the relative layout to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_list_pressed" />

    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_list_normal" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_list_pressed" />

</selector>
```

It is working on changing the background but not alpha of the contents.

Comment: One observation is that it MAY be that the `hasFocus()`didn't work because you didn't set your RelativeLayout to be focusable. Try adding `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in your RelativeLayout xml, it might be that `hasFocus()` will work. I know you solved it, but check it out, may help you in the future, because that would be a simpler solution than implementing a touch listener

Answer (score 0):

after some thinking i found a solution

```
public void pressed(final View view){
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                view.setAlpha(0.5f);
            }
            else {
                view.setAlpha(1.0f);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```